# В ListBox выводится в столбец, а не в строку

Tags: c#, winforms, button, listbox

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        ListNodes L = new ListNodes();
        L.AddRight(rand.Next(0, 100));
        L.AddRight(rand.Next(0, 100));
        L.AddRight(rand.Next(0, 100));
        L.AddRight(rand.Next(0, 100));
        L.AddRight(rand.Next(0, 100));
        L.AddLeft(rand.Next(0, 100));
        listBox1.Items.Add("    List0    ");
        for (int i = 1; i <= L.Size; i++)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(L[i].ToString());
        }
        ListNodes P = new ListNodes();
        P.AddRight(rand.Next(0, 100));
        P.AddRight(rand.Next(0, 100));
        P.AddRight(rand.Next(0, 100));
        P.AddRight(rand.Next(0, 100));
        P.AddRight(rand.Next(0, 100));
        P.AddLeft(rand.Next(0, 100));
        listBox1.Items.Add("   List1   ");
        for (int j = 1; j <= P.Size; j++)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(P[j].ToString());
        }
    }
```

Здравствуйте. Дело в том, что ListBox при нажатии на кнопку заполняется данными в виде столбца, а для дальнейшей работы необходимо, чтобы эти два списка были в строчном варианте. Объясните, пожалуйста, в чём ошибка. AddRange пробовал - ругается.

Comment: Так как вы создаёте две коллекции ListNodes, то сделайте и два ListBox'а, размещённых рядом. Или возьмите другой контрол, например, DataGridView с двумя колонками.

Comment: Если вам нужно, чтобы значения были связаны попарно, то создайте тип (класс/структуру) с двумя свойствами, в которые заносите два значения. И в ListNodes помещайте этот тип.

Comment: спасибо большое всем! очень помогло :)

Comment: Что именно помогло, на каком способе остановились? Опубликуйте своё решение как ответ (и потом примите его).